# save multiple parameters in a loop, rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, loops, parameters, controller

I've created a form with about 40 fields available to edit, I'm trying to save them to a database using the controller. I currently have this code:

```
c = Form.find(params[:id])
  if c
    params.each do |k,v|
    c.k = params[:v]
  end
```

Which doesn't work, I get this error: `undefined method 'k='`

if I was going to write them all out manually it would look like this:

```
c = Form.find(params[:id])
if c
  c.title = params[:title]
  c.reference = params[:reference]
....
etc.
```

Comment: try c.send(k) = params[:v]

Comment: @Rubyman that won't work the way you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're trying to update the attributes on your `Form` record based on what gets passed into `params`, try this as a basic outline:

```
c = Form.find_by_id(params[:id])
if c
    params.each do |k, v|
        c[k] = v
    end

    c.save!
end
```

Your original code's use of `params[:v]` was probably not doing what you were intending, and you really meant for it to be `params[:k]` instead. However there's actually no need to look up the value for that key inside the loop like that because you already have the value at hand in `v`.

Here's a quick rundown on the ways of interacting with `ActiveRecord` attributes: http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/06/28/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord/

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you are trying todo but your code seems to be very odd. Solution is as follow

```
c.send "#{k}=", params[:v]
```

Comment: I've updated my question as I'm not sure I've explained it correctly

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
c = Form.find(params[:id])
c.update_attributes(params[:form])
```

Note that I guessed the `[:form]` part in the second line, it depends on your form. check your html source, and see if your fields are something like this:

```
<input name="form[field_name]" ...
```

As you see, name contains an "array like" form. Check your HTML source and adapt (so if its `name="foo[field_name]"`, you need to use `c.update_attributes(params[:foo])`)